# EventEmitter and recursion

Tags: angular

When i have an template with selector `'recursive-element'`and its template looks like this

```
<li *ngFor="let x of y" (click)="greet($event)">
   <div *ngIf="x.children">
      <recursive-element [y]="x.children"></recursive-element>
    </div>
</li>
```

and in classs i have defined

```
greetEvent = new EventEmitter();
greet(e){
  greetEvent.emit("hello world!");
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

and in another component i added it to tempalte e.g

```
hi(x){
  alert(x)
}
```

when i click on the nested `recurive-element` the event does not trigger but when i click on first li element it does

Is it because of recursion so even is only bound to first recursive element not the nested one or is there something i missunderstood?

Comment: Nothing looks correct to me. Where is `@Output` API? Few things are missing I think..

Comment: Indeed ther are, but purpose of this code was just do demonstrate my point

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Custom events in angular2 are not [bubbled up](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2296) so you can either:

1. emit the parent event on `<recursive-element>` when one of the child emits an event - this will create a new `EventEmitter` per child.

In this case the child component should be like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'recursive-comp',
    template: `
        <div>
        <div *ngFor="let item; of tree;">
        <a href="#" (click)="onClick(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
        <recursive-comp *ngIf="item.children" [tree]="item.children" (clickEvent)="onClickChild($event)"></recursive-comp>
        </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class RecursiveCmp {
    @Input() tree = null;
    @Output() clickEvent = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {

    }

    onClick(item) {
        console.log("clicked", item);
        this.clickEvent.emit(item);
    }

    onClickChild(item) {
        this.clickEvent.emit(item);
    }
}
```

see this [plunker for event per child](https://plnkr.co/edit/atbIqtRdtTnXZFJf8Wq9?p=preview)

2. create a service that will hold the `EventEmitter` and will be used by both parent and children. For this to work the service should be a singleton and therefore the best option would be to register the provider at `bootstrap` time.

this is the service code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ClickerService {
   clickEvent = new EventEmitter();

   clicked(item) {
     this.clickEvent.emit(item);
   }
}
```

And the child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'recursive-comp',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let item; of tree;">
        <a href="#" (click)="onClick(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
        <recursive-comp *ngIf="item.children" [tree]="item.children"></recursive-comp>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class RecursiveCmp {
  @Input() tree = null;
  constructor(private clickerService: ClickerService) {}

  onClick(item) {
    this.clickerService.clicked(item);
  }
}
```

see this [plunker for service event](https://plnkr.co/edit/q5sQeqfEbfOphiJ98wf1?p=preview)

Comment: first method does not return child data , always sent parent data

    onClick(dir){ //pass item on click
        this.clickEvent.emit(dir);
        return;
    }

Comment: Thanks..I figured it was something like this ..seeing it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, but if you want a solution without using services, this worked for me.

Declare another EventEmitter as Input:
`@Input() eei: EventEmitter<any>;`

(you probably already have an EventEmitter as Output that works normally)
`@Output() eeo= new EventEmitter();`

Next, on ngOnInit(), set eei to your eeo variable if it is not yet.
`if(!this.eei) this.eei = this.eeo;`

Now, simply use the eei to emit since your eei is actually the top layer eeo.

(in your code you probably already have a eeo.emit(), just change it to the eei)